# Why is volatile variable usually private?

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

I have two classes - Class '`MyDerived`' derives from the abstract base class '`MyBase`'. Also `PrimaryDerivedClass` also inherits `MyBase`.
I first create the instance of `PrimaryDerivedClass` which then creates instances of '`MyDerived`'.

`MyBase` has a Protected method called `ProcessThread` which is used like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessThread)` when new instance of the `PrimaryDerivedClass` and `MyDerived` is created. Now when i want to stop all the threads in some scenario, I am setting some boolean volatile variable to TRUE and when any other thread find volatile variable's value = `TRUE`, it stops processing.

When I declared '`private volatile bool stopThreads`' in `MyBase`, I didn't get the intended behavior. However, when I made it `static` or `public` I could see what I am trying to acheieve.
What would be wrong in case of private volatile?

Keeping the above requirement aside, I have a question further:
**Usually, I have seen volatile variable is declared private. Is there any important aspect because of which it's usually declared private?**

(I am new to multithreading.)

Comment: You may want to avoid volatile: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2010/12/04/SayonaraVolatile.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No changing the access modifier from private to public won't have any effect on the behavior of the volatile field (at least not is volatility).  You have some other issue, which we can't make a guess on without seeing your code.

Debugging multi-threading is hard since the way the code executes is non-deterministic - you can't predict when precisely your threads will run.

The fact that volatile fields are private is that they are used for synchronization internally by the class.  They are part of it's implementation not its interface.

Comment: I agree with you. It works as expected when the volatile field is made static (without changing it to public). Does it make sense? And anyway, why is volatile variable kept private usually?

Comment: @CSharpLearning  Wait let me see here I'm thinking correctly you have multiple instances of the MyDerived class.  When you set stopThreads are you setting it on each instance you created or only once.  If stopThreads is non-static then each instance of the class has it's own copy - setting stopThreads only affects that instance.  Changing stopThreads to static makes all instances of the class share the same field - so there is only one shared copy to set.  If that's the case you issue has nothing to do with multi-threading and volative.

Answer (score 1):

Volatile fields are private because they are fields, not volatile. If you need to expose values, use properties, which allow you to hide implementation details.

In this case, maybe you'll change your `volatile Boolean` into a `ManualResetEvent` without needing to change any code calling `obj.StopThreads = true`. It may be argued that a a method named Stop() would be better than a property all together.

Answer (score 1):

This 'strange' behavior is merely because of the access modifier. Private means that this variable is accessible only from the class it was defined in. All derived classes don't have access to it so when you change base class's volatile variable's value it changes for *base class inner works only*.

All classes that inherit from the base should have their own implementation of stop-right-now. But everything changes when you set this variable as public (which means no access restrictions, it's accessible from everywhere) or static (which means the value is the same for all instances because it 'belongs' not to an instance but to class and is accessible by class name not by instance). If you want your variable to be accessible for derivatives you should mark it as protected.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx - this article shows the meanings of access modifiers.